# How do I authenticate with Google Calendar API? (PHP)

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have the **[Google Client PHP library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)** set up **[via Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient)** and Composer.

I have successfully followed **[this getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started)** to verify that I can use the Google Client. I followed the example and was able to retrieve a list of books through the Books API, but that's not what I'm actually trying to do.

I am creating a website for a company, and they want to have a form on their website that will allow users to request a meeting at a certain time, and then this will be automatically added to said company's Google Calendar.

In the Google Calendar API, I see a lot of information about using OAuth to have a user sign in and grant access to *THEIR* calendar, which can then be used, however this is not what I want at all. The user shouldn't have to sign in; the server should gain access to the company's Calendar and then make requests to that *SPECIFIC* calendar.

I have made a Public Access API Key in the Google API Console and entered it in my code, i.e.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName($applicationName);
$client->setDeveloperKey($developerKey);

$calendarService = new Google_CalendarService($client);
$calendars = $calendarService->calendars;
$results = $calendars->get($calendarId);

dd($results);
```

I learned of these methods by looking through the source. I have found that, at least on my Google Calendar, the $calendarId is simply my gmail address (found under Calendar Settings). However, this code returns an error:

```
Error calling GET
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/MY_EMAIL@gmail.comkey=MY_KEY_HERE: (401) Login Required
```

Of course, this is all wrong. I don't want the user to need to login. I just can't find any documentation on how to authenticate my app for this scenario. Every guide I come across assumes that the user will be able to sign in so I can access *THEIR* calendar. But I want the ***server*** to login and access a *SPECIFIC* calendar that belongs to the company.

Comment: Read https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount and https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount The PHP API client supports service accounts.

Comment: @AMS why not post that as an answer?

Comment: It was just a pointer, and a lazy pointer to start with. I call Google OAuth2 API mostly from Python so I don't have any nice example to give but, on the other hand, I find that Google focuses too much on Web-based auth leaving little emphasis on Service Accounts . Thus, that comment.